# 12V relay to disable a circuit while starting

Tags: relay, 12v

I’m looking for a relay for testing purposes. Not exactly sure what relay I need.I want to disengage ignition coil circuit when the starter solenoid is engaged. I am figuring that I’m running a wire from the starter solenoid to the relay and the coil circuit comes in one side of the relay and out the other and I would need a normally closed relay that disengages when power is supplied from the starter solenoid. Basically the engine would just be spinning over with no spark applied.

Comment: Why a relay? Why not just pull the wire off the ignition coil while testing?

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure. I am working on this for a friend that I won’t talk to her for a few days. He was originally wanting to do a push button that he can hold inside the vehicle, but kick around the idea of using a relay instead.